# R - Conditionally replacing values with values from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, metadata, autofill

I'm working in R and I have a very large dataframe (`bulk.df`) with a column for species IDs (`species`) and a column for survey site number (`site`). There are hundreds of observations per site and there are 25 sites, so there are thousands of rows.

I also have a separate data frame (`meta.df`) that contains the metadata for each of the 25 sites including survey depth (`depth`) and also a column for site number (`site`).

**I'd like to add a column for depth to the bulk.df** and autofill that column with the depth information associated with each site that is listed in the `meta.df`. I copied `bulk.df$site` and renamed it `depth` hoping to find a way to conditionally replace the site numbers in this column with depths from the `meta.df` .

suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Please can you use ``dput(head(bulk.df))`` and ``dput(head(meta.df))`` and edit your post to include the output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `base R`

```
merge(bulk.df, meta.df[c('site', 'depth')], by = 'site', all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dplyr::left_join` for that task

```
library(dplyr)

final.df <- bulk.df %>%
  left_join(
    meta.df %>% select(site, depth),
    by = "site"
  )
```

This will take the `meta.df` dataframe, select only the columns `site` and `depth` and join that onto `bulk.df`, using the common column `site` as a key to map the two tables.

Comment: Happy to hear! If it solves your problem, feel free to upvote or accept the answer :)